# Cannot downcast from 'UIViewController' to a more optional type 'SubclassOfUIViewController<NSString>'

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I have a Subclass of UIViewController that is defined as follows

```
@interface SubclassOfViewController<__covariant Type> : UIViewController
@end
@implementation SubclassOfViewController @end
```

I am sending this subclass as a segue from screen change.

Now in prepareForSegue I am trying to do the following

```
 public override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "embeddedScroll"){
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? SubclassOfViewController<NSString>!{
             vc.dataSource = genericDataSource
        }

    }
}
```

And receiving the following message:

```
Cannot downcast from 'UIViewController' to a more optional type 'SubclassOfViewController<NSString>!'
```

putting question marks instead of exclamation marks does not help.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually do not use Optional types for `as?` casting.

Try just removing that `!`.

```
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? SubclassOfViewController<NSString> {
```

Comment: how do I see how xcode converts Objective C code into Swift ?

Comment: @LenaBru, Cmd-click on the class name, and/or when viewing the .h file in the editor pane, use four-square icon and choose "Generated interface". (Sometimes Xcode fails to generate Swift interfaces, in such cases you may need to comment out some irrelevant parts causing errors.)